# Do all limit $\alpha \in \omega_1^L$ satisfy $L_\alpha \models V=HC$?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, constructibility, inner-models

In [*Gaps in the constructible universe, Marek and Srebrny, 1973*](https://zbmath.org/?q=Gaps%20in%20the%20constructible%20universe%2C%20Marek%20and%20Srebrny) a gap ordinal and the start of a gap are defined as follows

> $\alpha$ is a gap ordinal iff $(L_{\alpha+1}-L_\alpha)\bigcap \mathcal{P}(\omega) = \emptyset$
>
> $\alpha$ starts a gap iff it is a gap ordinal and $\forall\beta\in\alpha((L_\alpha-L_\beta)\bigcap \mathcal{P}(\omega) \neq \emptyset)$

They present the following Lemma and Corollary, the Corollary without any proof or comment:

> **Lemma 2.4.** If $\alpha$ starts a gap, then it is a limit ordinal.

> **Corollary 2.4.** If $\alpha$ starts a gap, then $L_\alpha \models V=HC$.

This presentation of course makes it seem as if every limit $\alpha \in \omega_1^L$ satisfies $L_\alpha \models V=HC$, but I haven't been able to prove this fact, and am not sure it's true.

I've also tried proving the Corollary by additionally using the fact that $\alpha$ starts a gap as follows:

As per the definition, this means there are in $\alpha$ arbitrarily big non-gap ordinals. By a result of Boolos mentioned in the article, if $\beta$ is a non-gap ordinal, there is an $E_\beta \in L_{\beta+1}$ such that $\langle Field(E_\beta), E_\beta \rangle \cong \langle L_\beta, \in \rangle$, where $Field(E_\beta) \subseteq \omega$. Thus, given an $x \in L_\alpha$, it'll belong to some $L_\beta$ such that there's an $E_\beta \in L_\alpha$, and thus $L_\alpha$ will prove $x$ countable, *given* the isomorphism between $L_\beta$ and $Field(E_\beta)$ also belongs to $L_\alpha$. But I'm not sure of this last fact. Checking the proof of Theorem 1 in [*Degrees of unsolvability of constructible sets of integers, Boolos and Putnam, 1968*](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0188.32701), the fact will be true if the Mostowski collapse is always definable in the constructible hierarchy in $\omega$ steps. More concretely, if when $S \in L_\beta$, then the function $mos: S \leftrightarrow mos(S)$ belongs to $L_\alpha$.

Comment: It is absolutely false that every $L_\alpha$ satisfies $V=\rm HC$ for limit $\alpha<\omega_1^L$. Just take an elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_2}$ and collapse to some $L_\alpha$, for example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Pun intended, or just good fortune?

Comment: @Noah: It's a $\Delta_1$ fortune.

Comment: The existence of the Mostowski collapse is often called Beta. Beta is not provable in KP but it is provable in KP + $\Sigma_2$-collection. So it's somewhere between $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ in the admissibility spectrum.

Comment: Regarding the "last fact" mentioned in the question, i.e. whether $L_\alpha$ has the isomorphism between $L_\beta$ and $E_\beta$: The Mostowski collapse can take longer than $\omega$ steps (consider e.g. recursive wellorders of $\omega$, which have Mostowski collapses cofinal in $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$). But if $\alpha$ starts a gap then $L_\alpha$ models ZF$^-$, and so can compute Mostowski collapses.

Comment: @FarmerS Thank you for your answer! The issue is, I'm not sure my proof of $L_\alpha \models ZF^-$ can go through without already knowing $L_\alpha \models V=HC$ (since I've changed the proof given by Marek to use more modern methods). And indeed, they present the proof of $L_\alpha \models ZF^-$ later, as if it were not necessary to show the truth of the Corollary.

Comment: @MartinS Fair enough. How about this? If $\beta$ ends a gap, then there is a surjection from $\omega$ to $L_\beta$ which is definable over $L_\beta$, without parameters. This follows from standard fine structure theory, and gives a surjection $\omega\to L_\beta$ which is in $L_{\beta+1}$. But for our purposes, it's enough to prove a slightly weaker thing: there is a surjection from $\omega$ to $L_{\beta}$ which is in $L_{\beta+2}$...

Comment: For this, fix the lexicographically least $p\in[\beta]^{<\omega}$ such that there is a real $x\in L_{\beta+1}\backslash L_\beta$ which is definable over $L_\beta$ from parameter $p$,
and fix a witnessing real $x$.  Let $H\preccurlyeq L_\beta$ be the definable hull of $\{p\}$ over $L_\beta$ (that is, $H$ is the set of all elements of $L_\beta$ which are definable over $L_\beta$ from $p$)...

Comment: Then $H\preccurlyeq L_\beta$, and by condensation, the transitive collapse $M$ of $H$ (exists and) equals $L_{\beta'}$ for some $\beta'\leq\beta$. But by elementarity, $x$ is also definable over $M$ from the transitive collapse $\bar{p}$ of $p$, and so $x\in L_{\beta'+1}$. By choice of $x$, therefore $\beta'=\beta$. And so by the minimality of $p$, therefore $\bar{p}=p$. It follows that $L_\beta$ is pointwise-definable from the parameter $p$. Let $\pi:\omega\to L_\beta$ be the resulting surjection...

Comment: Then $\pi$ is definable from the parameter $p$ over $L_{\beta+1}$, and therefore $\pi\in L_{\beta+2}$ (coding pairs appropriately, so that issues with ranks of pairs are avoided)...

Comment: Now suppose that $\alpha$ ends a gap. Then $\alpha$ is a limit of $\beta$'s as above, and hence for each such $\beta<\alpha$, there is a surjection $\pi:\omega\to L_\beta$ with $\pi\in L_\alpha$, and so $L_\alpha$ models "$V=\mathrm{HC}$".

Comment: @FarmerS Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! It's exactly what I was looking for and I understand the proof. In fact now, thanks to this insight, I've noticed an essentially equivalent proof can be confectioned from other results scattered across the paper. More concretely, its Lemma 8.1 states "If $\alpha$ is not a gap ordinal $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable", and its Lemma 4.1.a "If $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable, there's an arithmetical copy of it in $L_{\alpha+2}$". By checking this last proof, it is seen the isomorphism building the copy also belongs to $L_{\alpha+2}$.

Answer (score 5):

As Asaf mentioned, this is not true. It's indeed true that when $\alpha$ is a gap ordinal $L_\alpha\vDash\textrm{V=HC}$, but when considering some ordinals above gap ordinals we get points where it fails. For example, this example uses a result from Arai's ["A sneak preview of proof theory of ordinals" (p.17)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0596v1): let $\alpha$ start a gap of length $\alpha^+$ (where $\xi^+$ denotes the least admissible $>\xi$.) Then not only does $L_{\alpha^+}\vDash\lnot(\textrm{V=HC})$, but also $\omega_1^{L_{\alpha^+}}$ (i.e. what $L_{\alpha^+}$ thinks is $\omega_1$) is $\alpha$.

We can find larger cardinals $\kappa$ where this premise fails for $\textrm{V=H}_\kappa$ as well - the minimal $L_\alpha$ modelling ZFC satisfies powerset so it believes all sorts of accessible cardinals exist, but $\alpha$ is countable according to David Madore's ["A Zoo of Ordinals" (p.6)](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf#page=6).